# Find minimum number of customers that must have visited the bakery that day?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> A bakery sells three kinds of pastries -pineapple,
>   choclate and black forest. On a particular day,
>   the bakery owner sold the following number of 
>   pastries : $90$ pineapple , $120$ chocolate and
>   $150$ black forest. If none of the customers bought
>    more than $2$ pastries of each type, what is the 
>   minimum number of customers that must have 
>   visited the bakery that day ?

$a.)\ 80 \\
\color{green}{b.)\ 75} \\
c.)\ 60 \\
d.)\ 90 $

I have drawn the venn diagram and concluded that the visitors are $210$.

But that is not in options.

[image]

I look for a short and a simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Comment: As you have it, some people necessarily bought two, but it could be the case that they just bought one.

Comment: But I need to find the minimum no: of customers for that the no: of people to buy $2$ pastries should be maximum.

Comment: Ok, then 2 pastries of each type. So each customer buys 6 pastries in total. The answer is 75? Because I find 60.

Comment: In the question it is clearly stated that each customer can buy maximum $2$ pastries of each type , yes the answer given in book is $75$.

Answer (score 3):

You haven’t enough information to fill in the Venn diagram. (And what you’ve done is inconsistent with the data, since you have $120$ pineapple pastries.)

To get the smallest possible number of customers, you want each customer to buy as many pastries as possible consistent with the totals given. $150$ black forest pastries were bought; if each customer bought $2$, there would have been at least $\frac{150}2=75$ customers, and there can’t possibly be any fewer customers than that. Is $75$ customers enough to account for the other sales? Yes: for instance, it could be that $60$ of the customers also bought $2$ chocolate pastries each, and $45$ of them also bought $2$ pineapple pastries each. (Many other arrangements are also possible.)

It’s the black forest pastries that determine the lower bound on the number of customers, simply because more black forest pastries were sold than any other type.

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume that every one buys as much pastries as possible.

Clearly it will take the most customers to buy out all the blackforest ones.
Given the maximum of 2 blackforest pastries per customer we have
$\frac{150}{2} = 75$.

So b) it is. It's entirely not clear to me what you were trying to do with the Venn diagram tbh.

Answer (score 0):

If each costumer buys maximum of $2$ pastries of each type, then you can take the $150$ black forest pastries as the "worst case". So, if $75$ people bought each one $2$ black forest pastries, $60$ of the $75$ bought two chocolates and $45$ of the $75$ bought two pineapples, you cover all the pastries with the minimum of $75$ people.

Answer (score -1):

As $~90~$ is min.

So $~\frac{90}{2}=45~$ should be ans.

But it is not in options.

If we consider $~60~$ single pastries out of $~90~$ pastries are bought by $~60~$ customers and remaining $~30~$ pastries  are bought by $~15~$  customers each $~2~$. i.e.  $~(15*2=30)~$.

Min customers $~60+15=75~$.